# How can I make this javascript smaller?

Tags: javascript

As stated in comments, the goal is to pack in the functionality in the smallest chars possible.  I'll look into the minifiers but not expecting much, better than below.  Possible alternative implementations?

Contra (up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a)

Manually minified:

```
(function(f){var s=1;document.body.onkeydown=function(c){c=(c||window.event);c=c.charCode||c.keyCode;if((c==38&&(s|3)==3)||(c==40&&(s|12)==12)||(c==37&&(s|80)==80)||(c==39&&(s|160)==160)||(c==66&&s==1<<8)||(c==65&&s==1<<9)){s=s<<1;if(s==1<<10){s=1;f();};return;}else{s=1;}}})(function(){  alert('contra');  })
```

Much more readable:

```
(function (f) {
  var s = 1;
  document.body.onkeydown = function (c) {
    c = (c || window.event);
    c = c.charCode || c.keyCode;
    if ((c == 38 && (s | 3) == 3) || (c == 40 && (s | 12) == 12) || (c == 37 && (s | 80) == 80) || (c == 39 && (s | 160) == 160) || (c == 66 && s == 1 << 8) || (c == 65 && s == 1 << 9)) {
      s = s << 1;
      if (s == 1 << 10) {
        s = 1;
        f();
      };
      return;
    } else {
      s = 1;
    }
  }
})(function () {
  alert('contra');
})
```

Manually minified answer:

```
(function(f) {w=window;c="";w.onkeydown=function(e){e=e||w.event;c=c.substr(-9)+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode||e.which);if(c=="&&((%'%'BA"){f();}}})(function(){alert('contra');})
```

Comment: Posting minified code doesn't help. Please post full code.

Comment: Run it through Google Closure, or any other minifiers.

Comment: Start by formatting it so it makes sense. Nobody wants to sort through that crap.

Comment: Adjust the font size :-P

Comment: Please be specific , In what sense you are asking to make your javascript smaller????

Comment: Thx for reformat.  Should elaborate, the goal is to pack a small chunk of js in to acheive the contra code (up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my implementation of the Konami Code:

```
(function() {
  var code = "";
  window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    code = code.substr(-9)+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which);
    if( code == "&&((%'%'BA") {
      // do something awesome
    }
  };
})();
```

You can, of course, minify this to your needs.

Comment: No problem. Next time, try explaining your actual problem better :p

Comment: Yeah, I got too excited by the challenge and neglected the communication...  I can speak teh codez

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these services find out which makes it the smallest.

http://www.jscompressor.com/
http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify
http://javascript-minifier.com/ 
http://jscompress.com/ 
http://refresh-sf.com/ 
http://www.jsmini.com/‎
http://dean.edwards.name/packer/
http://www.blimptontech.com/

Answer (score 1):

Besides running it through a compressor, you could look through the tricks listed in this repo: https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques